# Ordered Fixed Length Combinations of a String

Tags: java, c++, c, string, combinations

I need to write a function which finds the possible fixed length combinations of a string. The need is that not all combis are required. For example, if the string is "abcde", and we need combis of length 3, then the function must return the following:

```
abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade
bcd
bde
bce
cde
```

and none else. I have been trying for it using recursion but things have not worked out as expected. I have also seen some similar questions but could not get much out of them. Algorithm or code(C, C++, Java), any help is welcome. Thanks.!

Note: The combinations need to be ordered. That is, the characters should follow the same order as in the input string.

Comment: Each combination you provided as an example is ordered. Is this a requirement? If so please state it in your question like: The resulting string must contain the characters in the same order as the original string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it's possible to do better, but this is what I could come up with quickly.

I used a `List` to preserve order, and had to avoid duplicates awkwardly.  Using a `Set` instead would allow us to skip the `result.contains(s)` check, but a better algorithm might avoid the duplicates in a cleaner way.

```
private static List<String> substrings(int i, String input) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (i == 0)
        return result;

    String first = input.substring(0, i);
    result.add(first);

    if (input.length() == i) {
        return result;
    }

    // Recursively find substrings of next smaller length not including the first character
    List<String> tails = substrings(i-1, input.substring(1));

    // Append first char to each result of the recursive call.
    for (String sub: tails) {
        String s = input.substring(0, 1) + sub;
        if (!(result.contains(s)))
            result.add(s);
    }

    // Add all substring of current length not including first character
    result.addAll(substrings(i, input.substring(1)));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems correct. Can you explain me the `for` loop condition : `for (String sub: substrings(i-1, input.substring(1)))`. It doesn't seem to be 'Java' though it gives no error.

Comment: This is an "enhanced for loop", using the result of a method call as the list being traversed.  I'll add a variable and some comments to the code to make it a tiny bit clearer...

Answer (score 3):

In the case of having three inputs, you have three indexes, initially set to the first three indices of the input string. Print that out, then increase the last index by one, and print out all indexes. Continue until you have reached the end of the input string, then you increase the second index and reset the third to the next after the second. Continue until the second index is second to last character, then increase the first index, and place the second and third in consecutive order after the first. Continue...

Let me try to illustrate:

```
Input:  [abcde]
         ^^^
         123

Output: abc

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
         ^^ ^
         12 3

Output: abd

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
         ^^  ^
         12  3

Output: abe

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
         ^ ^^
         1 23

Output: acd

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
         ^ ^ ^
         1 2 3

Output: ace

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
          ^^^
          123

Output: bcd

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
          ^^ ^
          12 3

Output: bce

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
          ^ ^^
          1 23

Output: bde

Next iteration:

Input:  [abcde]
           ^^^
           123

Output: cde
```

Comment: The combination can be of any length. The length three is just an example. If i need combinations of length 10, it would be hard to maintain 10 indices.

Comment: @shrey347 Dynamic allocated arrays, C++ vectors, etc. Always solvable. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Since your requirement is of a specific length of 3, split your `String` to chunks of 3 and then apply the algo.
2. Put aside one character from your `String` of 3, and compute possible permutations for the remaining 2.
3. Place that one character on all possible positions of the computed permutations.
4. Repeat above.

Comment: The requirement is not for specific length 3. It is just an example. The length of the combination can be variable for every function call. Say the function is Combi(String original, int SizeOfCombination).

Comment: It'll be easier for you to break down your problem to sub problems of the smallest possible units and then try to solve it. 3 should be pretty easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    char buf[6] = "abcde";
    int len = strlen(buf);
   // std::vector<std::string> char_list;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        for(int j = i+1; j < len;++j){
                //if (i==j)continue;
                for(int k = j+1; k < len;++k){
                        //if(i == k || j == k)
                        //      continue;
                        char temp[4]="";
                        temp[0] = buf[i];
                        temp[1] = buf[j];
                        temp[2] = buf[k];
                        temp[3] = '\0';
                        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
                        //show(temp,3);
                        //char_list.push_back(key);
                }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This shows quite a few more than specified.  You might want to look at the clarifications in the question.

Comment: o,sorry,the code error,i changed source code ...